# Join in linq: "The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Is it possible to make a join in linq and only return data from one dataset where the other key was present, a little like:

```
 var q = from c in customers
            join o in orders on c.Key equals o.Key
            select new {c.Name, o.OrderNumber};
```

and then instead of returning just the two records then returning customers like:

```
  var q = from c in customers
                join o in orders on c.Key equals o.Key
                select c;
```

When I try to do (something similar) I get this error:

```
The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.
```

Comment: Are both Customers and Orders in the same DataContext?

Comment: I agree with Stephen, are you using the same datacontext, the error message seems pretty specific.

Answer (score 0):

I going to assume that you've skipped a Where clause which involved the orders table (or otherwise the join would be pointless)

In which case, you can just have Linq infer the join.

```
var q = from c in customers
       where c.Orders.Any(o=> o.ProductCode == productCode)
       select c;
```

Linq2Sql will automatically create the Orders property if you have a foreign key defined; I believe with the Entity Framework, you have to manually specify it.

Comment: I'd hazard that he didn't skip it. After all, that first bit of code LOOKS right. Given the error text described, my assumption is that he's trying to combine two data contexts

Comment: I assumed that there was a WHERE because without it, the line could have been written as "var q = from c in customers select c;"

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates an other problem:
You have to use the same DataContext on every object in the query if you're using Linq to SQL.

Your code should look somehow like that:

```
using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
{
    var q = from c in dc.customers
            join o in dc.orders on c.Key equals o.Key
            select c;

    // process q within the DataContext
    // the easies would be to call q.ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will it be in EF 4.0 to create join from multiple context?

For example:

```
TestModelEntities e1 = new TestModelEntities();
        TestModelEntities e2 = new TestModelEntities();

        var d = from firme1 in e1.firme
                join g in e2.grad on firme1.grad.grad_id equals g.grad_id
                select firme1;
```